# How to choose only variables that have less than a threshold of correlation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a correlation dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    dt = pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.random.randn(3 * 50),
                       'var2': np.random.randn(3 * 50),
                       'var3': np.random.randn(3 * 50),
                       'var4': np.random.randn(3 * 50),
                       'var5': np.random.randn(3 * 50)})
    dt_corr = dt.corr()
```

I would like to create a list, which will contain the `var`s which:

- both `var`s of the pair, for the pairs that are correlated less than a threshold (in absolute value)
- for the pairs that have higher correlation (in absolute value), keep only one of the two `var`s.

how could i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you wanted to check the correlation value between 2 variables and if 2 variables are having high value, you wanted to keep one only.
For this you can use Heat map and from there you can check. Then you can drop the not desired columns.

Comment: Exactly, but I am looking for an automated process, so that I do not have to look at any plot

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

threshold_corr = 0.3
a = dt_corr.copy()
a = a.mask(np.triu(np.ones(a.shape)).astype(bool)).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'correlation'})
list(set(list(a[np.abs(a.correlation) <= threshold_corr ]['level_0'].unique()) + list(a[np.abs(a.correlation) <= threshold_corr ]['level_1'].unique())))
```